# Java serialization not writing to file

Tags: java, serialization

I have tried to serialize an object of type

```
HashMap<UUID, ArrayList<String>>
```

Knowingly, Hashmap is Serializable, UUID, ArrayList, and String are too.
I have debugged the value of the map, and the path, they're correct, no error is throws and the code seems to successfully run, however nothing is being written into the file...

Here's the code:

```
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(serializable);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Success serialization - " + serializable + " at path " + file.getPath());
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The results of the syso were valid, not a null nor an empty table, and a correct path, a file exists in that dictionary and everything...

does anyone know why it wouldn't work?
I tried googling but all I saw were cases where an error was thrown or an incorrect path was used etc...

**EDIT**

the "serializable" is the table. I made a serialize method taking a file and a Serializable type, and a HashMap is so it passes

Comment: How do you know there's nothing in the file? What is the file's length?  Did you open it and look inside?

Comment: I have, in fact.
I've opened it and it's completely empty

Comment: And the file length shows as 0 on a directory listing?

Comment: Wdym? when I debugged the inputted dictionary, it was with a value inside that I put for testing, however, when I deserialized it was null. when I said I opened I mean I've opened it on VSC to see it for myself. The weight of this file is also 0

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.
When I originally made the class that handled it, it also used another something that is made for something else(mostly human-readable text), which interfered with it.

I then tested by creating another class purely for serialization, and it worked!

I am sorry I bothered ya'll, and thanks for @markspace for the help!
Tho that it shouldn't have interfered.. it seems to have done it so I am glad I figured it out